# Add "selected" class to custom taxonomy dropdown search

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, search, terms

I found the following function to add a custom taxonomy dropdown to a search form. It works fine for searching, but it does not add the "selected" class to the searched-for term. Here is my code for the taxonomy named `grades`:

```
function get_terms_grades_dropdown($taxonomies, $args)
    {
        global $search_values;

        $myterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
        $output = "";
        foreach ($myterms as $term) {
            $root_url = get_bloginfo('url');
            $term_taxonomy = $term->taxonomy;
            $term_slug = $term->slug;
            $term_name = $term->name;
            $value = $term->term_id;
            if ($search_values['grades'] == $term->slug) {
                $selected = "selected='selected'";
            } else {
                $selected = '';
            }
            $output .= "<option value='" . $value . "' " . $selected . ">" . $term_name . "</option>";
        }

        return $output;
    }
```

Then I use the function like this:

```
<select name="grade" id="grade_search">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Grade Level</option>
    <?php
    $taxonomies = array('grades');
    $args = array('orderby'=>'count','hide_empty'=>true);
    echo get_terms_grades_dropdown($taxonomies, $args);
    ?>
</select>
```

The issue is with this line:

```
if ($search_values['grades'] == $term->slug) {
```

I need to get `$search_values['grades']` to equal the searched-for term.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$seach_values can be changed whenever the site redirect, be sure that `$search_values` still keeps the input values from your search form.

To be sure I suggest use `GET` or `POST` to pass the values from form. So, your comparing statement should be

```
$_GET['grades'] == $term->slug
```

Here I suppose your search form use `method="GET"`

Comment: Thank you. I replaced with your code above, but unfortunately did not solve the issue. I'm using this to add a taxonomy search to the "Events Manager" plugin. The code I found comes from "pharmadave" here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-events-manager-searching-by-custom-taxonomy

Comment: So, did you remember to Set
'$search_values['cat'] = 'your chosen items slug' before call that function?

Comment: I tried both `$search_values['cat'] = 'grades'` before the function AND directly as shown in my code above `$search_values['grades']` -- neither is working. I don't what's going wrong because the rest of the search works.

Comment: I'm not even sure what $search_values[] is... it's referenced as a global variable, but I can't find a reference to it anywhere in WordPress or the core Events Manager plugin...?

Comment: Could you show me the result if you add 
vardump($search_values);
vardump($term->slug);
right after foreach starts (After line: foreach ($myterms as $term) {)

Comment: $search_values was NULL. $term->slug = string(7) "grade-1" string(7) "grade-2" string(7) "grade-3" string(1) "k"

Comment: Here you see, $search_values was NULL.
It means that $search_values was not set values before the function called.

Comment: I see. But I don't know how to get the searched term. I've opened another question to learn how to get that. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/184848/get-the-selected-term-in-a-dropdown-search?noredirect=1#comment269830_184848

Comment: Don't hurry please, could you send me the template using that function, I mean the code of file showing the search form, and the code of file showing the search result (This file should show the search form also)

Comment: I got it! I needed to use $_POST. I did a var_dump of $_POST and found out what was being returned. Then I used `$_POST['grade'] = $term->id` and that worked. Your answer was correct based on the information I gave you. If you want to update it I will mark it correct.

Comment: That is what I mean. Thank for letting me know that way works. Ah, it's so nice. Mark it correct means that I have some reputation which I now need so much at least 15, you can see I have 1, I have no privilege. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23039/discussion-between-trangdinhvan-and-lindsay).