# Get the selected term in a dropdown search

Tags: search, terms

I am using the following function to create a dropdown search form and populate it with the terms of a custom taxonomy called 'grades'. The dropdown works for searching, but I can't figure out how to add the `selected` class to the selected term. See the variable in my function below `$SEARCHEDTERM` -- how can I get that to equal the searched term?

```
function get_terms_grades_dropdown() {

    $myterms = get_terms('grades');
    $output = "";
    foreach ($myterms as $term) {     
        $term_taxonomy = $term->taxonomy;
        $term_slug = $term->slug;
        $term_name = $term->name;
        $value = $term->term_id;
        if ($SEARCHEDTERM == $term->slug) {
            $selected = "selected='selected'";
        } else {
            $selected = '';
        }
        $output .= "<option value='" . $value . "' " . $selected . ">" . $term_name . "</option>";
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Have you passed term name in URL as parameter or anything?

Comment: No, there's nothing added to the URL.

Comment: Ok, then may be you have passed through POST method. First get selected term ID from `$_POST` and find its slug. You can use this `get_term_by`. After that compare that slug like you are currently comparing.

Comment: I did a var dump of $_POST and after I searched I got this: `array(7) { ["action"]=> string(13) "search_events" ["category"]=> string(2) "-1" ["grade"]=> string(1) "7" ["centercat"]=> string(0) "" ["country"]=> string(1) "0" ["near_distance"]=> string(2) "25" ["near_unit"]=> string(2) "mi" }`

Comment: A var dump of $POST['grade'] = `string(1) "7"` -- how I can get that in a usable format for the comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show dropdown with currently selected option, first you need to fetch
current value. You can get that value from `$_REQUEST` variable. If you have `grade` variable then your current value is $_REQUEST['grade'].

Eg.
`if ($_REQUEST['grade'] == $term->slug)`

**Recommended:**
Do not use REQUEST variable directly without sanitization. Use function like `esc_attr`. If you are sure that you need positive integer, you can use `absint`.
May be.

```
$current_grade = esc_attr( $_REQUEST['grade'] );
if ($_REQUEST['grade'] == $term->slug)
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me why I should use $_REQUEST['grade'] instead of $_POST['grade']?